# Editor for html/css/php/js/jQuery

Tags: ide, intellisense

It would be great to have something like intellisense or code auto-complete for php/js/jquery..

I'm using Windows, and I've tried only NetBeans so far, can you suggest another all-in-one IDE ?

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: Netbeans does have auto-complete for all of those, unless I misunderstood you.
http://netbeans.org/features/php/

Comment: yes it has, but I remember it was freezing for 2-5 secs sometimes on my laptop if I would have around 10 tabs open and I would try to switch between them, that's why I want to try something else...

Comment: Sounds like memory/resource hog issues to me ;)

Comment: actually I don't know... since I'm running Win7 on a core2duo laptop with 3GB ram ... 3MB cache, 800FSB .. I really think this is enough for an IDE... :)

Comment: Sublime Text - https://www.sublimetext.com/ It is a sophisticated text editor for PHP/HTML/JS/CSS code, markup, and prose for a slick user interface with extraordinary features and amazing performance. This rapid PHP editor is a proprietary cross-platform source code editor with a Python API and supports many programming languages. Web developers can also add markup languages and functions which can be added with the help of plugins either community-built or maintained under free-software licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse for PHP with aptana plugin works great for me. I had some trouble getting it to work, so I listed up all the steps to take.

1. Install Eclipse for PHP: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr1
2. Install Aptana 2 as Eclipse plugin: You do this by opening eclipse and going to *Help* -> *Install new software* and add this link: http://d3lq98emif3szr.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio/2.0.5.1278522500/
   Then select *Aptana Studio*, *next*, *next* and restart Eclipse.
3. Install JQuery support: do this by creating a temporary new default web project (*File* -> *New* -> *Project* -> *Web* (the first one) -> *Default Web Project*), Choose a name, Click *Next*, Click *Install Javascript Libraries* at the bottom of the window, Expand *Javascript Libraries*, select *JQuery Support* and click *Install*. Then *Next*, *next* and restart Eclipse
4. Change the default Javascript editor to Aptana JS Editor: In eclipse, go to *windows* -> *preferences* -> *general* -> *editors* -> *file associations*, click **.js* in the first list, then click *Aptana JS Editor* in the second one, and finaly click *Default* to make this your default Javascript Editor
5. Enable JQuery in the Aptana JS Editor: In Eclipse, go to *windows* -> *preferences* -> *aptana* -> *editors* -> *javascript* -> *code assist*, check *JQuery 1.3*, and finally click *OK*.

Now, all of your js-files (no mather if they are in PHP-project or any other project) will have JQuery auto-complete and documentation popups. If you would like to enable JQuery support for other file types (like *.html, *.tpl,...) do again as described in step 4, but instead of *.js, just select (or add) the desired filetype, and then make Aptana JS Editor the default. The only problem I have found is that, if you enable Aptana JS Editor for *.php, the php-editor doesn't work very good. You can work around this by either putting all your javascript in a JS-file (which is actually good practice), or you can enable the Aptana JS Editor for php everytime you want to edit some inline javascript, and just change it back to the default Javascript editor when you are done.

Comment: Thank you, very useful information. Have to try.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has autocompletion for PHP, HTML, javascript and Jquery

Answer (score 0):

[phpDesigner 7](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php) has all of the features you're looking for. It has built-in HTML, CSS, JS, PHP editor. Debugging tools, code completion, syntax highlighting, code checking etc, also supports popular JS frameworks. It's commercial but you can use trial version and see it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The best **free** editor for HTML/CSS/Jquery/PHP is [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/neonm4a)

The best **commerical** editor for HTML/CSS/Jquery/PHP is [**PHPStorm**](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=windows-version)